# How I can explain the Mean value theorem geometrically?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

How I can explain the Mean value theorem geometrically?.

Comment: Please do not edit a question to change its meaning.  Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Wikipedia article on the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem). It says that

> ... given a planar arc between two endpoints, there is at least one point at which the tangent to the arc is parallel to the secant through its endpoints.

Image from Wikiepdia article:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way can be through using the link between tangents and derivatives.

Let $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ be some points on the graph.

Slope between the points is given by $\dfrac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$, you can argue that there's a point $(c,f(c))$ which has the same slope as $\dfrac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$ and this is given by $f'(c)$